# When sharing a url in an app via UIActivityViewController, and Firefox is installed on iOS, no title appears on sharesheet

Tags: ios, swift, firefox

In my app I allow sharing of URLs. When I share a URL using the standard iOS share sheet, and a user has Firefox installed, they have the option of opening the URL in Firefox. When you tap the Firefox icon it brings up a custom Firefox share sheet.

At the top it shows simply the url. When I do the same thing using the Washington Post app, I see both the title of the page and the url below it.

I can see that the delegate method

```
activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, subjectForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?)
```

is never getting called, so it's never picking up the title.

Does anyone have any idea how the Washington Post is getting both the title and the url on the Firefox share sheet?

Comment: Did you find any leads on this problem? I'm confronting the same thing.

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't had any luck yet.